# Product of all primitive nth roots of unity is 1?

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Is the product of all primitive nth roots of unity equal to 1? Equivalently, is $\Phi_n(0) = 1$ for $n>2$?

More exactly, I'm trying to prove that
$$x^{\phi(n)} \Phi_n(x^{-1}) = \Phi_n(x).$$

Since 
$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\substack{k = 1 \\ (k,n) = 1}}^{n} \left(x - e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}} \right),$$
and since the inverses of all primitive nth roots is still the set of primitive nth roots, we have
$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\substack{k = 1 \\ (k,n) = 1}}^{n} \left(x - e^{-\frac{2k\pi i}{n}} \right)$$
and so
$$\Phi_n(x^{-1}) = \prod_{\substack{k = 1 \\ (k,n) = 1}}^{n} \left(x^{-1} - e^{-\frac{2k\pi i}{n}} \right) = \Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\substack{k = 1 \\ (k,n) = 1}}^{n} \left( \dfrac{e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}} - x }{xe^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}}\right). $$

I have basically finished, because $\phi(n)$ is even so I can switch around the terms in the parantheses, but I still need the products of primitive nth roots of unity to be equal to 1.

Comment: Yes, they come in pairs $\omega$, $\omega^{-1}$, unless $n=1,2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n \neq 1,2$, then if $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$'th root of unity, then $\zeta^{-1}$ is a different $n$'th root of unity, so in this case the answer is yes. If $n = 2$, then $-1$ is the only primitive square root of unity.

Comment: This is repeating the answer by lhf.

Comment: I didn't know, I just answered the question.